# JavaMelody PDF Report: Customizing the generated PDF Report

Tags: pdf, java-melody

We have introduced JavaMelody v1.94.0 to monitor some Jakarta EE Applications at the customers. So far good.

However, in the production environment, the customer is not happy with the content of the generated PDF Report. In fact, the customer only wants to see the Statistics for SQL Queries, HTTP Requests and performance indicators at the method level.  Other Statistics like the Diagrams and the System Information, especially the User Sessions must not appear in the generated PDF Report.

Failing to meet these requirements will lead to not adopting JavaMelody at all.

We have perused the User Guide, to see whether there are parameters to exclude blocks of content from the PDF Report, but so far no success.

Hence, my question: Is it possible to customize the content of the generated PDF Report, and if yes, how do we achieve this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate cross posted at https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/issues/1159